# Resize Width of MenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I want to put a gap between menustrip and form at right of menuStrip.
I used autosize= false and new size properties, height of menustrip is changed but width is not changed. Menustrip's width remain same with form's width.

```
menuStrip2.AutoSize = false;
menuStrip2.Size = new Size(50, 90);
```

I can not change from Desing-> Properties -> Size, too.

I only create a gap from menustrip's right to form's left.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.aspx should give you a good idea of how / when to access items.

Comment: And take a look at how to correctly use size... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size.aspx It looks as though perhaps you need to set the size of the buttons, the buttons are probably larger than you are setting the menustrip and the menu strip is resized automatically to accomodate, just like a DIV acts.

Comment: Just set the Dock property to None.  Probably add the right anchor, can't really understand menustrip's right vs form's left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you do this at design-time:

1. Create a new form.
2. place two panels on this form. Call them `panelTop` and `panelFill`. Set there dock properties to `Top` and `Fill` respectively. Resize `panelTop` to the height you want you menu strip to be.
3. Add another panel to `panelTop`, call it `panelTopRight`. Dock this panel `Right`.
4. Add your menu strip. Set the dock property to fill.
5. Right click on `panelTopRight` and 'Send to Back'. Now you can resize the `panelTopRight` to allow the gap that you require.

If you want to do this at run-time you will have to perform all of the above in code; but that is perhaps another question...

I hope this helps.

Comment: Killercam..! Isn't it better to use ToolStripContainer instead. We may resize the container then.

Comment: You can do what the OP wants with a `ToolStripContainer`. He wants a menu at the top and did not mention being able to reposition the strip - in which case this is the best and simplest way to go... Plus, with the above you are still free to resize the menu ass you wish, the menu is bound to the height of `panelTop`.

Comment: *You can't do what the OP wants with a `ToolStripContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

Open xyz.designer.cs file, then look for Windows Form Designer generated code after that see for events generated for menustrip items then,

this.menuStripnameToolStripMenuItem.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 81, 4);

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?